# Is a function from $\Bbb{R}^+\times\Bbb{R}^+\rightarrow\Bbb{R}^+\times\Bbb{R}^+$ injective and/or surjective?

Tags: functions, solution-verification

The function is defined on $\Bbb{R}^+\times\Bbb{R}^+$ as $f(x,y)=(2x+y, xy)$

I know the usual way to prove $f$ is injective is to assume $f(a,b)=f(c,d)$, and then show that this implies $(a,b)=(c,d)$.

That leads to two equations: $2a+b=2c+d$ and $ab=cd$.

I struggled to manipulate these, so I wondered if the function is not injective, and can I find a counterexample? I was lucky to realize that $f(3,4)=f(2,6)=(10,12)$. So the function is not injective, but I still haven't proved it in general, i.e. without relying on a specific counterexample.

The proof for surjective would look like: Assume $(a,b)\in\Bbb{R}^+\times\Bbb{R}^+$. Can we find, in terms of $a$ and $b$, $(x,y)\in\Bbb{R}^+\times\Bbb{R}^+$ such that $f(x,y)=(a,b)$?

Again there are two equations: $2x+y=a$, and $xy=b$

Solving the first equation for $y$ and substituting into the second equation leads to the quadratic equation $2x^2-ax+b=0$.

Using the quadratic formula, we get a discriminant of $a^2-8b$, which can easily be made negative by choosing $b>\frac{a^2}{8}$.

Does that mean any ordered pair $(a,b)$ satisfying $b>\frac{a^2}{8}$ is not in the image of the function?

Comment: " So the function is not injective, but I still haven't proved it in general, i.e. without relying on a specific counterexample."  One single counter-example destroys *everything* so yes you have proven it and you don't need anything more.

Comment: I understand that, but I'm just frustrated by not being able to do the algebra on those equations to get a general format for all counterexamples.

Comment: A counter example to surjectivity can come from intuition of the AM/GM inequalitly.  $a= 2x+y > x+ y \ge \sqrt{xy}=\sqrt b$ so choose a very large $b$ and a small $a$. $f(x,y) = (1,5000000)$.  Then $2x+y=1$ so $0< x< \frac 12$ and $0< y< 1$.  But that meanx $xy < \frac 12 < 5000000$.

Comment: Also intuitively we can disprove injectivity by noting $2a+b = 2c+d$ and $ab =cd$ is two equations with four unknowns which in general will not have a unique solution.  Fix two of them and solve for the other two should give a multiple number of solutions.  If for intance you fix $a,b$ you get $c=\frac{ab}d$ and $\frac {2ab}d+d=2a+b$ do $d^2-(2a+b)d+2ab=0$ and $d=\frac{(2a+b)\pm\sqrt{(2a+b)^2-8ab}}2=\frac{(2a+b)\pm(2a-b)}2= 2a,b$.  Select $d= 2a\ne b$ and we have $f(a,b)=f(\frac 12a, 2b)$... but any two fixed will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So the function is not injective, but I still haven't proved it in general, i.e. without relying on a specific counterexample.

A single counterexample is all you need.  You don't need to prove it in general.  If a *single* counterexample exists then the statement isn't true.

And if the statement isn't true..... then it's not true.

.......

However if you don't want to randomly grasp for counterexamples you can attempt to prove it *is* injective, find the snag, and point out it will fail for a class of counter examples.

i.e.

$2a+b=2c+d$ and $ab=cd$

If we let be $b = 2c-2a +d$ and then $a(2c-2a+d)= 2ac -2a^2 +ad = cd$ so

$d(c-a)= 2ac -2a^2 = 2a(c-a)$.

If $c=a$ then we do get that $b=d$ and $(a,b) = (c,d)$ but if $c\ne a$ then we get $d=2a$ and $b=2c$.

And we will always have $f(a,b)=f(\frac 12b,2a)= (2a +b, ab)=(2(\frac 12 b)+2a, \frac 12b\cdot 2a)$.

so any such $(a,b) \ne (\frac 12b, 2a)$ will be a counterexample.

But a single counterexample is good enough and probably easier.

(The way *I*'d do it: is to let $xy = 0$ so if $x = 0$ we get $f(0,y) = (y,0)$ and if $y = 0$ we get $f(x,0) = (2x, 0)$ so if $y=2x$ and $x=1$ and $y=2$ we get $f(1,0) = (2,0)$ and $f(0,2) = (2,0)$..... FWIW)

surjectivity:

> Does that mean any ordered pair (a,b) satisfying b>a28 is not in the image of the function?

Yeah, I think so.

Let see.  If $f(x,y) = (4, 3)$

Then $2x+y=4$ and $xy = 3$.  $y= 4-2x$ so $x(4-2x) = 3$ so $8x^2-4x+3 =0$ so $x =\frac {4\pm \sqrt{16-4*3*8}}{16}$ has no (real) solution.

It's not surjective.

Good job!

Comment: Thanks for the details. Poor word choice on my part to say "I didn't prove it in general". I know one counterexample is all it takes. I just meant I was interested in a proof that doesn't use a counterexample.

Comment: Well, you can prove a counterexample exists.....

Comment: What you and @José Carlos Santos provided is more powerful because given any $(a,b)$, there is a formula to find another point with the same image. And that formula also shows that this function is two-to-one.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof of the fact that $f$ is not injective is fine. What else do you want?

If you want to, you can say that you always have $f(x,y)=f\left(\frac y2,2x\right)$. But, as I wrote, what you did is enough.

And, yes, you proved correctly that $f$ is not surjective too. I would have done it the same way. In particular, yes, you have proved that if $b>\frac{a^2}8$, then $(a,b)$ is not in the range of $f$.

Comment: Thanks, that general form you provided is what I was looking for. How did you arrive at that?

Comment: I solved the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}2x+y=2a+b\\xy=ab\end{array}\right.$$and I got two solutions. One of them is the trivial one: $(x,y)=(a,b)$. The other one is $(x,y)=\left(\frac b2,2a\right)$.